# SVG/Inkscape - "Failed to load the requested file"

Tags: html, svg, inkscape

Hopefully someone out there knows about SVG files. I'm just running through a Mozilla tutorial about SVG graphics and one of the exercises is reviewing this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="200" height="280" xmlns="http://www/w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <polyline points="40 60 80 20 120 60" stroke="black" stroke-width="20"
                stroke-linecap="butt" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
    <polyline points="40 160 80 120 120 160" stroke="black" stroke-width="20"
                stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polyline points="40 260 80 220 120 260" stroke="black" stroke-width="20"
                stroke-linecap="square" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel"/>
</svg>
```

It's supposed to create a graphic of three angles pointing upward.
I have 8 other SVG files which convert to Inkscape without any problem. But the graphic from the code above will not convert over to Inkscape, and Inkscape gives me this error: *"Failed to load the requested file"*
Is there something I'm missing? I've tried to change all the parameters in the code thinking maybe the graphic is too big but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I just created another SVG file and it converted to Inkscape without a problem: `<svg width="200" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <path d="M 10 75 Q 50 10 100 75 T 190 75" stroke="black" 
              stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="5,10,5" fill="none"/>
        <path d="M 10 75 L 190 75" stroke="red"
              stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="5,5" fill="none"/>
    </svg>`

Comment: Inkscape is supposed to be able to read polylines, but not write them. Can you confirm that Inkscape (which version?) does not read polylines?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own question. I converted the SVG file to an HTML, and I opened the file in my browser and the graphic is displayed!